# Net start MongoDB - system error 2

Tags: mongodb, database

I've just downloaded mongodb 3.2 version and went through the installtion using [mongodb manual](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#install-mongodb-community-edition).

My mongodb directory is in `c:\mongodb\`.

When I try to run net start MongoDB command using cmd in superuser mode
it says :

```
system error 2 has occurred.
the system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: did you have "C:\data\db" directory?

Comment: @profesor79 yes i do have this directory

Comment: To start MongoDB, run mongod.exe. For example, from the Command Prompt:

C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe - probably you need set PATH or go directly to bin folder to call mongod

Comment: yes i can run mongo manually but i need to start mongod then mongo every time, it's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove mongoDB as a service first before installing it again if you are not using MongoDB for the first time.

`mongod --remove`

then install mongoDB service again in your own mongoDB folder.

`mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log --logappend --rest --install`